# Frequent or rare?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

Which common thing do these words have uncommonly in common?

mole kiss breath

Mates! Please note, if you haven't found the answer yet - it helps you find your way back to the real world.

Comment: Is that last statement correct? "until you have NOT found the answer"?

Comment: can you answer my clarifying comment/question?

Comment: Oh yesss I can. Everything around here is correct I ensure.

Comment: thanks.  now I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: Why , otherwise what would have been your answer ? I am open to discussion to a certain extent.

Comment: I would have expected it to say "until you have found the answer" (no "not" in there).  The "not" confuses me.  And I do have something that all of these things have in common ("air"), but the "not" makes it seem like I need to make incorrect guesses to find the correct answer, which seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Also note, that this final note, whether it provides additional clue or not, is just an additional note. Take it or leave it. The question itself ends with "breath".

Comment: It is a big mess. The correct one is the last one, although the hungarian translation is not correct (the translator's problem) . It is either "as long as you don't find the answer, it helps you find your way back" or either "until you have found the answer, it helps you find your way" or as is currently: "if you have not found the answer yet, it helps you find". Pick the one that fits better in English. :)

Comment: Your most recent edit drastically changed the meaning of the hint.

Comment: Was your follow-up question addressed to me?  (1) If you are addressing a comment to a person, you should *address* it to them, e.g., by saying ‘‘@Peregrine’’.  (2) I can’t make any constructive comment on how the question should be worded, because I have no idea (well, very little idea) what it means.  “… they ***rarely*** have this thing associated to them”?  Does that mean that *sometimes* they do, but *usually / often* they don’t?

Comment: But you "had a spark" that it must be badly worded. . Now you have no idea.  I would say let the conclusion be that the question stays the same, the previous (deleted) answer is incorrect:)

Comment: Please note, Peregrine Rook, that the most recent edit was made by me (the author), and the one before it was made by a person who did not have the faintest clue what he was editing, just wanted to correct the grammar (I appreciate that he wanted only good! He provided translations too to help me clarify, but the translations of the translator were chaos)

Comment: After your comment on DivideByZero's answer, I think I understand what we're looking for now. We're looking for something that these three words *sometimes* have in common, but don't *always* have in common. The thing we're looking for is itself common, and "helps us find our way back to the real world". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sometimes=rarely, your last quote+"as long as you don`t know it". Otherwise yes, it is.

Answer (score 5):

Is it...

> a human head

This would make sense because

> A human head can have moles, it kisses, it breathes, and it is used to help find your way back to the real world (in the form of consciousness and rational thought).

Comment: I like this! Just it is not uncommon for a human head to have these. And how common is a human head? It is relative.